# Python variable variables without eval?

Tags: python, variables, eval, variable-variables

Is there is a way to access variables using a variable string in python? For instance, I would like a neater way than using `eval` for the following:

```
def toggleListButtons (self):
    buttons = ["flip", "remove", "removeAll", "delete", "deleteAll", "loadDirectory"]
    for button in buttons:
        eval("self." + button + "Button.setEnabled(!self." + button + "Button.isEnabled())")
```

Comment: +1 good question because eval is evil

Comment: how evil? very. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [getattr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in function. There is also [hasattr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hasattr) and [setattr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr).

```
button = getattr(self, 'flipButton')
button.setEnabled(True)
```