# Variably variable variables: werkzeug LocalProxy

Tags: python, variables, flask, werkzeug

I'm trying to set werkzeug LocalProxy from varying tags.

The best I've been able to do so far is:

```
for tag in self.filters.iterkeys():
    c = "{}_context".format(tag)
    setattr(self, c, LocalProxy(lambda: getattr(_request_ctx_stack.top.g,
                                                tag,
                                                None)))
```

Where if there is an attribute x set on g (g.x), my_instance.x return g.x

BUT what I really want to do is to format c above to return the local proxy without digging through my_instance

```
x_context = LocalProxy(lambda: g.x)
```

instead of what I can do now:

```
my_instance.x_context = LocalProxy(lambda: g.x)
```

only its from a list where I might need to return g.x for x_context, g.y for y_context, etc.

Doing:

```
c = LocalProxy(lambda: getattr(_request_ctx_stack.top.g, tag, None))
```

above does not work.

Its sounds even more convoluted now as I write this out, and I'm not grasping it this very second, so let me know what clarifications are in order.

EDIT:

For the curious, here is the context of where this is from:

https://github.com/thrisp/flarf/blob/master/flask_flarf/flarf.py

Comment: What is `my_instance`? Is it `self` in your example code?

Comment: my_instance would be an instance of MyClass, which relates to self in the above snippet.

Comment: What is the `_request_ctx_stack.top.g` for?  Is that meant to access a local variable called `g`?

Comment: Yes, g is part of Werkzeug & Flask, basically a per request place to put things.

Comment: What do you mean by "digging through my_instance"?

Comment: I want to set the local proxy object to return through 'x' instead of 'my_instance.x'

Comment: It still isn't clear.  What do you mean by "return through 'x'"?  Do you mean set a local variable called 'x'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python variable variables without eval?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111358/python-variable-variables-without-eval)