# Python variable variables in "main"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to automatically define variables using a dynamic string, similar to `${$a}` in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

As I do this in a plain script I do not have objects and therefore can not [apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111358/python-variable-variables-without-eval) `setattr` or am I wrong?

How do I dynamically define variables?

Comment: use a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You can store the variables you want in a dictionary. That's basically what php does, only in Python you can specify which dictionary to use and how to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify local or global dictionary:

```
>>> locals()['xxx'] = 'Hi'
>>> xxx
'Hi'
>>> globals()['yyy'] = 'Hello'
>>> yyy
'Hello'
```

Comment: Don't. Use a dedicated dict instead.